# Построение модели конечного автомата

Tags: теория-автоматов

Построить модель кодового замка с пятью кнопками *(А, Б, В, Г, Д)*, открывающегося при наборе кода *В * Д* и остающегося открытым, пока нажата кнопка *Д*. Символ * Є *Y* означает, что ни одна кнопка не нажата, символы *А, Б, В, Г, Д Є Y* соответствуют нажатой кнопке.

Множество *Q = {q0, q1}*, где *q0* - замок открыт, *q1* - замок закрыт.

Я так понял, что:

1. *Y = {А, Б, В, Г, Д, *}* - конечный входной алфавит
2. *Q = {q0, q1}* - конечный выходной алфавит

Теперь проблема в определении состояний множества состояний А:

```
a0 - зажата кнопка Д;
```

А вот дальше я не пойму как определить состояния

Comment: @AndrewSage, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @DreamChild, я тоже сначала не до конца прочитал, там не "реализуйте за меня", там вопрос по заданию.

Comment: @AndrewSage, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @AndrewSage, если честно, просто не знаю, как все это принято описыать в студенческих работах, а по сути все просто.

В соответствии с описанием у автомата будет 4 состояния

- А0 -- закрыт

- А1 -- готов к открытию 1

- А2 -- готов к открытию 2

- А3 -- открыт

и возможные переходы  (в скобках после состояния символ, по которому осуществляется переход) 

    А0 -> A0, A1(В) 
    A1 -> A2(*), A0  
    A2 -> А3(Д), А0
    А3 -> А3(Д), А0

Ну, а выход во всех состояниях, кроме А3, естественно, *`q1`* (как это формально принято описывать -- не знаю).

--

Надеюсь, чем-то помог.

Comment: >там не "реализуйте за меня", там вопрос по заданию

@Fike просто вопрос был поправлен впоследствии

Comment: @DreamChild, действительно, вопрос подвергался многочисленному редактированию.

IMHO самое интересное (и видимо ставящее автора в тупик) там было

      и как вообще возможно набрать комбинацию _В*Д_, где *- означает, что ни одна кнопка не нажата

(не понимаю, почему эта фраза исчезла?).

--

@AndrewSage, все довольно просто. Представьте, что Вы опрашиваете клавиатуру с некоторой частотой (например, 5 раз в секунду). Тогда все становится на свои места (хотя, физичеси открыть такой замок сможет далеко не каждый) -- между отпусканием кнопки В и нажатием на Д нужен интервал 0.2 сек.

Answer (score 1):

Я понимаю, что немного запоздал с ответом, но

> А вот дальше я не пойму как определить состояния

Вам нужна лишь входная строка (последовательность нажатых кнопок), а не возможные состояния замка. В этой строке вам нужно, чтобы была последовательность "ВД", а после неё кнопка "Д" была нажата чётное количество раз (т.к. вы первым нажатием на кнопку - нажали, а вторым - отжали, то суммарно, вместе с "ВД", вам нужно, чтобы "Д" была нажата нечётное число раз). В вашем случае вы можете вводить это строку посимвольно.

Если я правильно понял ваше условие, то замок откроется лишь если была нажата комбинация "ВД" и замок будет оставаться открытым, пока кнопка Д не будет нажата ещё раз. Таким образом у вас должны быть следующие состояния в автомате:

q0: Стартовое состояние, с которого вы начинаете. В этом состоянии если вы читаете "В" - переходите в состояние q1, если читаете любой другой символ - остаётесь в q0.

q1: если прочли символ "Д" -  перешли в состояние q2, если прочли "В" - остались в q1, во всех других случаях - возвращаетесь в q0.

q2: конечное состояние. Если нажали "Д" ещё раз - то переходите в q3, во всех остальных случаях остаётесь в q2.

q3: Если нажали "Д" - возвращаетесь в q2, во всех остальных случаях остаётесь в q3.

Таким образом - переходы между состояниями q0, q1 и q2 гарантируют вам нажатие клавиш "ВД", а переходы между q2 и q3 гарантируют, что кнопка Д будет в нажатом состоянии.